# How to speed up scrolling in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll, paging

I want to make paging/scrolling in UIScrollView to be faster, so when the user lefts his finger the next page will come faster than normal regardless the speed of the acceleration.

Comment: I've tried `decelerationRate` property but nothing changed.

Answer (score 13):

Tweak the `decelerationRate` of your UIScrollView.

More reading: [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal`, `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you've setup the ScrollView to snap to pages (pagingEnabled = YES).  When the the user lifts their finger you want it to snap to the closest page quicker than what it currently does?

If that's what you're trying to accomplish, this is what I recommend:

- DISABLE pagingEnabled (pagingEnabled = NO).  We're going to do it ourselves.
- Setup some object (probably the ViewController) as a delegate of the scroll view.
- In the Scrollview delegate, override the method `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`.  You will also want to override the method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` so that you can get the velocity of the drag.
- In the `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`, you can calculate the direction of the drag (using the velocity you got from the other method) and the offset to the nearest page.  From there, it's as simple as setting the contentOffset of the scrollview using a `UIView` animation block with the desired duration.  For example:

`[UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
    scrollview.contentOffset = calculatedCGPoint;
}];`

That should give you the desired effect.